# Taking out drivers code from kernel Source and compiling it as out-of-tree module

Tags: linux, module, driver

I am trying to take out the driver code from Linux kernel and want to compile it separately as out-of-tree module.

What Makefile Modification is needed? and How to pass Kconfig parameter?
You can take out any drivers .

say for example for inside kernel you compile xgbe driver using

make M=drivers/net/ethernet/amd/xgbe modules

I want to take out xgbe out of kernel and compile it seperately against kernel
installed. (it might to fail to compile due to changes ) but if running kernel is
same as the taken out module it should compile fine.

Comment: There are various sites with module Makefiles and descriptions: [minimal](https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html), [Makefile + related](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/07/write-linux-kernel-module/), and [lots more](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+kernel+module+makefile+example)

Comment: Also the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)

Comment: i know how to make Makefile, I want some sort of Script that can do this in an automated way for in-kernel drivers.
Use case of this is , you want to modify some driver which is present in kernel , u cant do it untill you  compile and load the kernel , with this u should be able to modifydriver without updating/modifying kerne.